# How to compare items in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say i have a dictionary within a dictionary like so:

```
Allusers={
User1: {'Film1': Vote1, 'Film2': Vote2}
User2: {'Film1': Vote1, 'Film2'; Vote2}
...

}
```

I would need the logic/algorithm/formula to compare every person to the other persons, just once.
How would I need to approach this ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Define 'compare'. What are you looking for?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think for the question the *comparison* is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

Allusers={
    'User1': {'Film1': 'Vote1', 'Film2': 'Vote2'},
    'User2': {'Film1': 'Vote1', 'Film2': 'Vote2'}
}

for comb in combinations(Allusers, 2):
    if Allusers[comb[0]] == Allusers[comb[1]]:
        print '{0} is same with {1}'.format(comb[0], comb[1])
```

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: You're right, Code changed.

Answer (score 0):

something like :

```
users={
User1: {'Film1': Vote1, 'Film2': Vote2}
User2: {'Film1': Vote1, 'Film2'; Vote2}
User3: {'Film1': Vote1, 'Film2'; Vote2}
User4: {'Film1': Vote1, 'Film2'; Vote2}
}
keys=list(users)
for i,x in enumerate(keys):
    for y in keys[i+1:]:
        #compare users[x] and users[y] here
```

here in the first loop `User1` will be compared to users `2,3,4` and in the next loop `User2` will be comapared to users 3,4 only as he's already comapared to `User1` in the first loop.

Comment: @user413734: The `combinations` solutions are far more readable and memory efficient than this one.